# Varying style in nested navigation menu

Tags: css, html

I'm developing a nested navigation menu in html5 using ul ul ul li, but I want the width of the 3rd tier element to be different according to which top level menu element is selected.  So if I start with menu item 1, I want the bottom level element to be 100px wide, but if I start with menu item 2, I want the bottom level to be 200px wide.

I thought I should be able to use an inline style definition to redefine the style for ul ul ul li in between the html code for the top level items in the list, but I can't find the right syntax.  Firstly, am I going about this the right way? If so, what is the syntax?

```
ul ul ul li { width:100px }
```

doesn't seem to work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly but will help you understand how to manipulate child elements through CSS.

You can use nth-child to choose from a list of children, the following style selects the thrid line from all unordered lists.

```
ul li:nth-child(3) {  
  color: #ccc;
}
```

see https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ to see how it works.

Or my simple example: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shootermatic/me2s92ts/)

Comment: That's great! Thanks.  So my CSS is now:
#nav_menu ul li:nth-child(1) ul ul li {
 width: 100px;
}
#nav_menu ul li:nth-child(2) ul ul li {
 width: 200px;
}
and that works exactly as I wanted.  Thanks again.